# How close can I fly to a bridge?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, visual-flight-rules

I want to take some pictures of a bridge. How close can my pilot get me?

Comment: You might be better off finding a drone operator if that's feasible. They seem to be taking over the market for aerial photography

Answer (score 11):

If operating under VFR rules, which your pilot probably is if he's attempting to stop you actually *hitting* the bridge in question and allow you good enough visibility to take a photograph in the first place, the rules vary slightly by location.

The FAA regulations will be as follows (Note: all emphasis mine - indicating what I believe is the interpretation of your bridge)
:

> An aircraft must maintain an altitude of 500 feet above the surface [and], the aircraft may not be operated closer than 500 feet to any person, vessel, vehicle, or **structure**.

and

> An aircraft must maintain an altitude of 1,000 feet above the **highest obstacle** within a horizontal radius of 2,000 feet of the aircraft over any congested area of a city, town, or settlement

Also note that helicopter rules differ slightly.

> Helicopters may be operated at less than the minimums prescribed in [the previous quoted sections] if the operation is conducted without hazard to persons or property on the surface.

<sub>source: [14 CFR 91.119 - Minimum safe altitudes: General.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.119)</sub>

And the UK CAA rules are similar

> An aircraft must not fly closer than 500 ft to any person, vessel, vehicle, building or **structure**.

and

> [...] it must not fly less than 1000 ft above the **highest fixed object** within 600m of the aircraft.

---

So, in summary your pilot can get you within 500ft if it is an uncongested area, 1000ft if its a congested area - closer if he's got a helicopter and can do it without causing a hazard.

Comment: CAA rules for helicopters are not relaxed. A helicopter must not fly closer than 500 ft to any person, vessel, vehicle, building or structure except for the purposes of taking off or landing.

Comment: @Simon ok, bad wording. I took out the "relaxed" - but is my quote below that not an accurate summary of the Helicopter differences for VFR flight? (Ive added my source)

Comment: HI Jamie.  I wasn't critiquing, just adding info.  The CAA has no such variation.  Your answer is fine.